# How would I calculate an derivative with two unknown variables?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm learning calculus II. I recently wondered what if I had two unknown variables in an function, and wanted to take an derivative.

Let's say there is a function $f(x,y)=2x^3+7y^2$

How would I calculate $\frac{df}{dx}$ ? What about $\frac{df}{dy}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're differentiating with respect to $x$ , $y$ is constant. So just treat $y$ as constant (given that $y$ is not a function of $x$)

So

$$\frac d{dx} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=6x^2+0=6x^2$$

If $y$ is a function of $x$ then,

$$\frac d{dx} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=6x^2+ 7.2y.\frac {dy}{dx} $$

The other part, if $x$ is not a function of $y$

$$\frac d{dy} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=0+14y=14y$$

if $x$ is a function of $y$ then

$$\frac d{dy} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=2.3x^2.\frac {dx}{dy}+14y$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac d{dx} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=6x^2+0=6x^2$$

$$\frac d{dy} \left( 2x^3+7y^2\right)=0+14y=14y$$

Comment: But, you're treating "the other" variable as a zero, when it is unknown...

Comment: $y=f(x)$ or $f(x,y)=2x^3+7y^2$?

Comment: $f(x,y)=2x^3+7y^2$

Comment: Then $\frac{df}{dx}=(2x^3)'+(7y^2)'=6x^2+0=6x^2$, because $y$ -const